# Write $(h \circ f)^{-1}$ when $h(x)= x \ln(3 + x)$ and $f(x) = x^2 − x$

Tags: functions, inverse

I have arrived up to a point but haven't solved it yet:

$$(h \circ  f)^{-1} = y= (x ^2 − x )· \ln(3 + x^ 2 − x)$$

$$ x = (y^ 2 − y )\cdot \ln(3 + y^ 2 − y)$$
Any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: Hint: $(h\circ f)^{-1} = f^{-1}\circ h^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither $h(x)=x\space ln(3+x)$ nor $f(x)=x^2-x$ are injective ($h(0)=h(-2$)= $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and infinitely many other examples).Hence there neither $h^{-1}$ nor $f^{-1}$

Comment: thank you @ataulfo for your help!